Prisma type inference is returning weird types
I'm encountering an issue with TypeScript not properly inferring the types when using PrismaClient in my Node.js typescript application.
Setup:

Prisma Schema:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                String   @id @default(uuid())
  telegram_id       BigInt   @unique
  telegram_username String?  @unique
}


Prisma Client Initialization:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
export default prisma;



Issue:
When I perform a simple findUnique query, TypeScript infers the type as a complex Prisma type instead of the expected model type.
const getAccount = async (telegram_id: number) => {
    const account = await prisma.account.findUnique({
        where: { telegram_id: telegram_id.toString() },
    });

    return account;
};

// Testing type inference
const testTypeInference = async () => {
    const account = await getAccount(123456);

    if (account) {
        // TypeScript should infer that account is of type Account
        // but instead it infers a complex Prisma type
        console.log(account.telegram_username);
    }
};

testTypeInference();

Expected Type:

account should be inferred as Account | null.

Actual Type:

account is inferred as Prisma__AccountClient<Account | null>.

Question:
How can I ensure that TypeScript infers the correct type (Account | null) for the result of the findUnique query without needing to manually set the types?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
